# Excel still recalculates when hiding a row despite CalculationManual

Tags: vba, excel

Excuse me if duplicating, but couldn't find anything in regards to my problem on the internet.

So I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Then somewhere down the script there is

```
For Each sheet In sheets
    If sheet.Cells(i, ColBrand).Rows.Hidden Then
        sheet.Cells(i, ColBrand).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
```

, where ColBrand is just a column number defined as a constant integer in the beginning.

And so it goes through an array of worksheets hiding rows where necessarity doing its job just fine.

Problem is, despite CalculationManual, "calculating: xx%" still pops up in a status bar occasionally. Which, alongside with the speed of execution, leads me to thinking Excel recalculates the entire Worksheet (possibly Workbook) after hiding each row. Which is sad.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

---

Now I'm thinking, could it be because I have a couple of VBA written Application.Volatile functions on one of the Worksheets?

---

I do have this function, which gets called under a condition, which triggers WorkSheet_change event. If this is of any help

```
Function get_rand(floor As Long, ceiling As Long, exceptions() As Long)

Dim rand As Long, _
    position As Variant

If UBound(exceptions) - LBound(exceptions) + 1 >= 999999 Then
    get_rand = "error"
Else
    Do Until IsError(position)
        rand = CLng(((ceiling - floor + 1) * Rnd() + floor))
        position = Application.Match(rand, exceptions, False)
        get_rand = rand
    Loop
End If

End Function
```

---

Oh btw the code above interacts with sheets which have WorkSheet_Change routines themselves. Target.Adress 'es of these do partly intersect but get neither changed nor updated by the code above. Could it be the cause?

Comment: Apologies. Shown piece of code unhides rows, but there is a EntireRow.Hidden = True somewhere down the scrpit as well.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. As an experiment I set calculation to manual, defined a function which contained  `Application.Volatile` , called it from the worksheet, hid the row that contained the formula, and then unhid and saw that it didn't recalculate. Thus, it seems unlikely that it is the hiding of the rows per se which is causing this. Your question has very little detail, so it is hard do anything more than guess what is going on with your project. Can you try to come up with a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: One debugging idea: In the volatile UDF's put the line `Debug.Print Application.Caller.Address & Now()` and check out the immediate window after running your macros to see where and when these functions are calculating. That way you could either confirm or disconfirm your suspicion that they are running when they shouldn't be.

Comment: when setting calculations to manual, does that apply just to one sheet, or does it apply to the whole workbook?

Comment: @ForwardEd  The code snippet shows application-wide mode setting, but that is still a good question. Perhaps they are inadvertently toggling it on and off between each sheet. The code snippet doesn't show just where calculation is being turned back on. Presumably somewhere, but doing so at the wrong time could cause unwanted calculation.

Comment: While snippets can be good in terms of focusing in on specific areas, you can miss the bigger picture when you dont see the whole thing.  Other then stepping through line by line and watching what is happening, is there a syntax other than `Application.Calculation = ` that could  toggle the calc that could be searched for?  Is it possible to turn a worksheet to manual calc and have the rest of the workbook automatic?

Comment: @JohnColeman i've been trying but i can't replicate the exact behaviour. Another thing I've noticed is that I can see excel hiding rows (row by row) while executing the script.
Speaking of volatile, I do have Application.Caller somewhere in Public Functions, as well as Rnd.

Comment: @JohnColeman is there any way to check if Application.Calculation modes switching when looping through Worksheets is not my case?

Comment: @invyspirit Put `Debug.Print` statements before any line which switches it back on.

Comment: @JohnColeman ah, simple as that!
so no known "feature" that would override CalculationManual? I guess I should debug.print after every line of code then :)

Comment: Any calls to any Solver routines? They mess with the calculation mode.

Comment: @OldUgly nope, no solver, no goalseek. But thanks for pointing out that such would force calculation and god knows what else

Comment: Oh btw the code above interacts with sheets which have WorkSheet_Change routines themselves. Although Target.Adress 'es of these do not intersect neither get changed/ updated by the code above.

Answer (score 0):

This [MS Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687891(v=office.15).aspx) discusses this problem.

It states "The user can trigger recalculation in Microsoft Excel in several ways, for example:" ... "Deleting or inserting a row or column."

I think you've stumbled upon a documented "feature".

Comment: Thanks! So you think Excel treats hiding/ unhiding a row/ column as deleting/ inserting one?